# How to use Tamil in NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans, encoding, netbeans-8, tamil

I have set my project properties to `UTF-8` encoding and installed all my native language (Tamil) fonts. I have tried to use `Tamil` words but it displays only as boxes.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBeans uses Monospace font as its default font and this font may not have all the unicode characters you need.  The solution is to change the default font of NetBeans editor windows and also to change the font of NetBeans output window which needs to be done from different places.

**Changing Default Font of NetBeans**

1. Invoke menu Tools > Options
2. In the tab Fonts and Colors change the default font to some other font

[image]

**Changing Font for Output Window**

1. Right click on the Output window and choose "Settings.." option
2. Change the Font from the font box

[image]

When I tried changing the font to Arial Unicode and type unicode tamil characters this was what I could get...

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot **Tushar Joshi**. Clean and clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

Using Tamil font in Netbeans 8.2

1. Go to tools
2. Select option
3. Select Fonts & Colors
4. Change font to Nirmala UI
5. Click apply and then Ok

Same thing applies for output

1. go to Miscellaneous
2. Click on Output
3. First option change font to Nirmala UI
4. Click on Apply and then Ok

Input font change
[image]

Output font change

[image]