# How to type in Tamil in java(swing components) using Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, encoding

By this method, I am able to use it in Netbeans but not in the Swing GUI components, like a text box
[How to use Tamil in NetBeans 8.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750841/how-to-use-tamil-in-netbeans-8-0-2#comment57267173_34758184)

[image]

Comment: Does the linked question give you absolutely ***no*** hint? What is the font used by the label in your GUI?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you. I thought the entire frame's font should be changed. Got it done now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :) Now you might answer the question in the (non-comment) text area below, or simply delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font of the respective Text field/ button or any element is to be changed to the respective font (i.e) Arial Unicode MS in this case.

It is the same as enabling other languages in the IDE. The same procedure of changing font is done to the corresponding element.

Answer (score 0):

Use fonts that supports the required language.

For Tamil language, you can use Fonts like Latha.

You can install [More Tamil Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=tamil) and use that in Java

Example,

```
Font latha = new Font("Latha", Font.PLAIN, 14);
JLabel label = new JLabel("தமிழ்");
label.setFont(latha);
```